# Update data WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called client and I am trying to update the contact number, but for only the id that is typed in. I have a form that creates two textfields for the data to be changed. My problem is im unsure on how i can only update data for only the id that is entered.

Code:

```
<form method="post" name="update" >
Client ID:
<br>
<input type="text" name="clientid"><br>
Contact Number:
<br>
<input type="text" name="contactno"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"><br><br>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$client = $_POST['clientid'];
$contact = $_POST['contactno'];

$result= $pdo->prepare ("UPDATE client SET client_contact_number='$contact' WHERE client_id='$client'");
$result->execute;
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens with this code? You are open to SQL injections and should update your driver.

Comment: When I pressed the submit button, I update the database to see the changes and nothing happened.

Comment: Is error reporting on? You never terminate the `mysql_query` line. Did you establish a `mysql` connection.

Comment: That's where im going wrong. How do I execute the query?

Comment: `mysql_query` executes the query (maybe, not if using PHP 7+) but you need a DB connection. Since you haven't done this dont even bother with `mysql_*`. Start with PDO, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php, it'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: I do have a DB connection it is created in another page and I used require to call that page and the top of this one. Ive edited my question.

Comment: Show the connection without credentials.. (also the prepared statement is incorrect)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax should be:

```
mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query)
```

you're missing the `$connection` object in your method.

PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

**Original version of this question used procedural syntax - hence my answer.*

Comment: If you use the object-oriented version, typically `$con->query(...)`, this is never an issue. It's also less verbose.

Comment: The OP has been edited, the original version used procedural syntax which is why I answered with the same. Agree about using the OOP version though.